# Why it does show me only shortcurts of data

Tags: php, forms, post

```
<?php
if ($_POST['button'] == "wyslij") {
/* sprawdzam czy dane zostaĹ‚y wysĹ‚ane z formularza */
  $plik = "1.txt";
  if (is_writeable($plik)) {
  /* sprawdzam czy plik jest do zapisu */
    if (!$handle = fopen($plik, "a")) echo "Nie mogÄ™ otworzyÄ‡ pliku...";
    if (fwrite($handle, $_POST['nazwa']." || ".$_POST['opis']." || ".$_POST['gatunek']."
") === FALSE) echo "Nie mogÄ™ zapisaÄ‡ danych do pliku...";
      else echo " "; /* hmm co tu wpisaÄ‡ */    
    fclose($handle);


  } else echo "Plik nie istnieje lub jest nie do zapisu...";
}
?>

<form action="1.php" method="post">
Nazwa Plyty: <input type="text" name="nazwa" /><br />
Opis: <input type="text" name="opis" /><br />
Gatunek: <input type="text" name="gatunek" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="button" value="wyslij" />
</form>

<?php
$plik = "1.txt";
$dane = file($plik); /* pobieram dane z pliku i zapisuje do tablicy (linia = rekord) */


for($i=0;$i<count($dane);$i++) { /* przeszukujÄ™ tablicÄ™ */
  //print_r(explode(" || ", $dane[$i]));
  list($nazwa, $opis, $gatunek) = explode(" || ", $dane[$i]);
   /* dziele liniÄ™ na tablicÄ™ i zapisuje dane do odpowiednich zmienncyh */
   $r[] = array(
      'nazwa'=>$nazwa,
      'opis'=>$opis,
      'gatunek'=>$gatunek,
    );
}
//print_r($r);
for($i=0;$i<count($r);$i++) /* przeszukujÄ™ tablicÄ™ */
   echo $r[$i]['nazwa']." ".$r[$i]['opis'].", ".$r[$i]['gatunek']."<br />";
   /* wyĹ›wietlam dane */

?>

<?php
$plik = "1.txt";

if ((isset($_POST['usun'])) AND (is_numeric($_POST['usun']))) {
/* sprawdzam czy zmienna $_POST['usun'] zostala zainicjonowana i czy jest cyfrÄ… */

$r = file($plik); /* pobieram dane z pliku */
unset($r[$_POST['usun']]); /* usuwam wybrany rekord tablicy */

$f = fopen($plik, "w"); /* nawiÄ…zuje poĹ‚Ä…czenie z plikiem i kasuje jego zawartosc */
foreach($r as $linia){
   fputs($f, $linia); /* wprowadzam linie po linii do pliku */
}
fclose($f); /* zamykam polÄ…czneie z plikiem */

}

?>

<form action="1.php" method="post">
<select name="usun">
<?php
$r = file($plik);

for($i=0;$i<count($r);$i++) {
   echo $r[$i]['nazwa']." ".$r[$i]['opis'].", ".$r[$i]['gatunek']."<br />";
}

for($i=0;$i<count($r);$i++){
   echo '<option value="'.$nazwa[$i].'">'.$r[$i]['nazwa']."</option>";

}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="usun" />
</form>
```

In the first part of code I have a option to add new lines of data and show off them. Moreover I would like to works another option to remove(delete) data which I created, but something goes wrong. Instead of show off full name of data it shows me a shortcut and  also removing it does not work.

Comment: Show the error or the ouput please

Comment: What do you mean by "shortcut"?